# ValidationError: 1 validation error for StuffDocumentsChain __root__

Tags: machine-learning, prompt, openai-api, langchain

I am getting this error `ValidationError: 1 validation error for StuffDocumentsChain __root__ document_variable_name context was not found in llm_chain input_variables: ['chat_history', 'user_query', 'relevant_context'] (type=value_error)`
while using `load_qa_chain` I have searched this error but did n't find anything related to this. Can anyone tell what I am missing here.

Code:

```
template = """You are a chatbot having a conversation with a human.

Given the following extracted parts of a long document and a question, create a final answer.

{relevant_context}

{chat_history}
Human: {user_query}
Chatbot:"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(
input_variables=["chat_history", "user_query", "relevant_context"],
template=template
)

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", input_key="user_query")

llm = OpenAI()
llm_chain = LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=prompt,
    memory=memory,
)

chain = load_qa_chain(
    llm, chain_type="stuff", memory=memory, prompt=prompt
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass two variables:
1-Context
2-Question
This is a limitation.

```
qs="How are you?"
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["context","question"], template=template)
qa_with_sources = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(model_name="gpt-4",temperature=0.2), chain_type="stuff",chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": PROMPT}, retriever=docsearch.as_retriever(), return_source_documents=True)
llm_response = qa_with_sources({"query": qs})
```

Use it like this and it will work!

Comment: please use the code editor for your answer to be more understandable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding Langchain requires `{context}` in the template

The modified code below should work.

```
template = """You are a chatbot having a conversation with a human.

Given the following extracted parts of a long document and a question, create a final answer.

{context}

{chat_history}
Human: {user_query}
Chatbot:"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(
input_variables=["chat_history", "user_query", "context"],
template=template
)

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", input_key="user_query")

llm = OpenAI()
llm_chain = LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=prompt,
    memory=memory,
)

chain = load_qa_chain(
    llm, chain_type="stuff", memory=memory, prompt=prompt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chain = LLMChain(llm=llm_model, prompt=PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=['context', 'prompt']))
```

If you assign prompt variable inline, it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
# Here is the solution which worked for me:
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
from langchain.memory import (
    ConversationBufferMemory
)
from langchain_openai import OpenAI

template = """
The following is a friendly conversation between a human and an AI. The AI is talkative and provides lots of specific details from its context. 
If the AI does not know the answer to a question, it truthfully says it does not know. The AI ONLY uses information contained in the "Relevant Information" section and does not hallucinate.

Relevant Information:
{chat_history}

Conversation:
Human: {input}
AI:"""
prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["chat_history", "input"], template=template)

# Assuming settings.LLM_MODEL_NAME and memory are defined elsewhere
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.9, streaming=True)

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)
memory.chat_memory.add_user_message("hi, my name is Abbas!")
memory.chat_memory.add_ai_message("what's up?")
memory.load_memory_variables({})

## ConversationChain or LLMChain
conversation = LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=prompt,
    verbose=True,
    memory=memory)
conversation.invoke("Translate this sentence from English to French: I love programming.")

# Hope it will be clear, let me know if I can help you, thanks
```